# Expandable Height RecyclerView

Tags: android

I'm recently tried RecyclerView component from Google, it's an amazing and powerful than ListView.
The problem is when use it in ScrollView, I was using [ExpandableHeightListView](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/make-android-listview-gridview-expandable-inside-scrollview/), it was working properly, but I want to turn to completely using RecyclerView.
Can anyone help me to find component like ExpandableHeightListView? or How to use RecyclerView in ScorllView?

Comment: Ma be this would help you  https://github.com/levelup/Expandable-RecyclerView

Comment: @Sadiq this Expandable recyclerview not expandable height recyclerview